# Improving UIWebView initialization time

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiwebview

My company uses a `UIWebView` to display ads. The issue I'm having is that initializing a `UIWebView` appears to be expensive; profiling with Time Profiler shows `[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,500)]` to take 31–40ms. This is enough to cause noticeable frame drops in games running at 60 FPS.

Is there a way to workaround this slow initialization time? My current ideas are to create a `UIWebView` when the app launches (but before gameplay has started), and reuse that (potentially creating a pool of them to reuse, like how `UITableViewCell` works) or to try and see if `WKWebView` has better performance.

Comment: call the function after a time delay.you can use dispatch or perform selector.

Comment: @IOS I don't think that will help because the webview still has to be initialized on the main thread. Initializing the webview after a time delay just pushes back the point at which we take the performance hit.

Comment: @MaxGabriel I never notice that it costs so much time to initialize a UIWebView. What IOS mean is to do the initialization in another thread using dispatch or NSOperationQueue.

Comment: @Danyun `UIWebView` must be initialized on the main thread, along with almost all UIKit classes (there are some exceptions like `UIImage`). The [`UIView` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html), under "Threading Considerations" do state that creating the view object itself may be possible on a background thread, but I've empirically verified that dispatching to a background thread and creating a UIWebView will very quickly get you `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: @MaxGabriel Appreciate for your explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my findings:

1. `WKWebView` does not initialize any faster. Creating `WKWebView`s took a similar amount of time as creating `UIWebView`s (in the 1 test I did, it took 46ms to create two `WKWebView`s.
2. The very first web view created takes significantly longer to create than subsequent web views. The first one takes 31–42 ms; subsequent ones take ~11ms to create. The good news here is that creating the first web view when e.g. the app launches allows future webviews to be created more cheaply, avoiding a 40ms hit while the game is running.
3. Creating a pool of `UIWebView`s was a good solution for my use case. By creating the webviews at app launch and then reusing them, I avoid causing a frame drop while the game is running.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference in the responsiveness between `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` because `WKWebView` has been introduced for a consistency matter between iOS and OSX. The underlying engine is Webkit in either way and it requires a lot of initialization.

The best solution I've found recent during years has been fading a `WebView` starting from a view with 0.1 alpha in which the url was loaded. Be careful to not start from 0.0 and do not have your webview detached from main view hierarchy because your url would not be loaded.

When `didFinishLoading` is called then you can fade it to 1.0 thus providing a better user experience.
Personally I don't like the `UIWebView` pool because I have experienced some memory troubles when maintaining it, especially on iOS 7 devices.