# How to get UserAgent for WKWebView without initializing UIWebView or WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I know we can initialize a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` then inject JavaScript to get the value of `navigator.userAgent`, however that requires the initialization of `UIWebView`, which [takes much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811906/improving-uiwebview-initialization-time). Is there a way to get UserAgent faster?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the *exact* `userAgent` string, you can ignore this answer.

If, however, you are interested in the info encoded inside the `userAgent` string, you can get most/all of them with other APIs... e.g. you get the device type with `UIDevice.current.model`; the browser type is Safari/Mobile Safari (didn't check what's the exact string but this value is unlikely to change); the platform obviously is iOS; etc.